# NodeJs - Error in code for string encryption/decryption

Tags: node.js

i am new to Node js.
Trying to run a simple Node Js code to encrypt a string:

```
module.path.push('./node_modules');
var Cryptr = require("./node-crypt"),
    cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');

var encryptedString = cryptr.encrypt('bacon');

cryptr.decrypt(encryptedString);
```

Getting error:

```
module.path.push('./node_modules');
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node samples\sample.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Please help me. I just want to encrypt and decrypt a string.

Comment: Can you share the git link? If there is a repo. I can look into the code.

Comment: No its just a sample.js file I created. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here's the code for encryption:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
function encrypt(text){
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc','d6f3Efeq');
    var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}

var c=encrypt('npci@123');
console.log("Encrypted string: "+c);
```

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_crypto.asp
Encryption Example (doesn't work as of 2018-09):

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var mykey = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', 'mypassword');
var mystr = mykey.update('abc', 'utf8', 'hex')
mystr += mykey.update.final('hex');

console.log(mystr);  //34feb914c099df25794bf9ccb85bea72
```

Agreed the referenced sample didn't work.  Updated encryption using later APIs

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-128-cbc', 'mypassword');
var encrypted = cipher.update('abc', 'utf8', 'hex')
encrypted  += cipher.final('hex')

console.log(encrypted);
```

Hashing Example:
From: https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/crypto/

```
var filename = process.argv[2];
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

var s = fs.createReadStream(filename);
s.on('data', function(d) {
  shasum.update(d);
});

s.on('end', function() {
  var d = shasum.digest('hex');
  console.log(d + '  ' + filename);
});
```

Update - plain HASH example without reading from a file:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

const plain = Buffer.from('some string', 'utf-8');
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
shasum.update(plain);
var hash = shasum.digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

I am showing both encryption and hashing to demonstrate the depth.  Encryption can be "undone" while hashing cannot.  Also caveat - not all encryption is created equal.  The algorithm and key length are important decisions that need to be matched to your problem.

Comment: In the above encryption example some error is there:
**TypeError: mykey.update.final is not a function**

Comment: In the above Hashing example there its giving an error:
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:636:11)
    at ReadStream.open (fs.js:1996:6)
    at new ReadStream (fs.js:1983:10)
    at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1931:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node samples\sample.js:9:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Comment: @AdarshSingh Made some changes to the crypto one.

Comment: @AdarshSingh also added hash example for you - when reading from a string.